# iOS - is it possible to have user-defined/custom media for push notifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, pushwoosh

I'm reading through documentation for both iOS and Android and cannot see it specifically mention what I'm trying to do.

What I'd like users to be able to do within app is select a sound from a playlist (I can define them with the bundle but also wondering if it's possible for them to record a sound and use this) and also select an icon - both of which I would like to use with their push notifications.

So, for example: A user is in the app, sets a reminder, selects an icon and sound for that reminder and saves. Obviously there is local/remote notifications so, again, I'd like to know if this is possible for either.

Apple states [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6) that

> For remote notifications in iOS, you can specify a custom sound that
>   iOS plays when it presents a local or remote notification for an app.
>   The sound files can be in the main bundle of the client app or in the
>   Library/Sounds folder of the app’s data container.

Does this mean a user can define their own sound for the notification or will I have to pre-define a list for them to select from?
I also haven't seen anything about user-defined/custom icons rather than pre-bundled ones.

I'll be using [PushWoosh](https://www.pushwoosh.com/) so I don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: From the docs it seems that you can let user upload their own tracks, save track to Library/Sound under your app folder, and play it when the notification comes! Predefined sounds work as well, of course.

Comment: @Flying_Banana Awesome!! Thank you :) any idea regarding the icon - would they be able to upload their own and once the push notification is sent to them it uses that icon? Or even using a pre-defined one? Please also add your response as an answer so I can accept once you have responded regarding the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple allows you to use sounds stored in your app's folder, which means you can prompt users to upload a sound, save to that folder, and use it as the notification track. You can also use predefined tracks in your app bundle. However, notifications can only display your app icon, as that is how users know the notification is from your app!

Note that you can't save the uploaded sounds to the main bundle as it is read only! If you can, you will be able to change icons of your app after user downloads it, among other crazy stuff!

Comment: Thank you, just accepted as I completely forgot about it. Do you think the sounds for push notifications can be a selection from their own device's music playlist?

Comment: It is definitely doable because I've seen custom alarms drawing music from my own music library. I think the media framework apple provides allows you to do this.